# How $M_T$ is well-define in this statement of optional stopping theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I'm reading about optional stopping theorem from [this](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf) note. In **Optional stopping theorem, version 3.** below,

- $a, b>0$ and
  $$
  T=\inf \left\{n \in \mathbb{N}: M_n \leq-a \text { or } M_n \geq b\right\}.
  $$
- $M_{T \wedge \infty}$ is the a.s. and $L_2$ limit of the stopped martingale $(M_{T \wedge n})_n$, i.e., $M_{T \wedge n} \to M_{T \wedge \infty}$ a.s. and in $L_2$.

The author then says that $\color{blue}{M_{T \wedge \infty}=M_T}$. I don't see how $T$ is almost surely finite.

> Could you explain how $M_T$ is well-define?

---

**Stopped martingale.** Let $\left(M_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ be a martingale and $T$ be a stopping time with respect to a filtration $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$, without any further assumption. Let us also define the stopped process
$$
\left(M_{T \wedge n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)
$$
where $T \wedge n=\min \{T, n\}$ by definition. Then this stopped process is also a martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right.$ ) (we skip the proof here, which uses the first version of the optional stopping theorem).

**Theorem 14.2. (The martingale convergence theorem: first version)** Let $\left(M_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right.$ ) be a square-integrable martingale (i.e., a martingale such that $\mathbb{E}\left(M_n^2\right)<$ $+\infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N})$ with respect to a filtration $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$. Under the additional assumption that
$$
\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}\left(M_n^2\right)<+\infty
$$
there exists a limiting random variable $M_{\infty}$ such that

- (i) $M_n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow \rightarrow} M_{\infty}$ almost surely.
- (ii) $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left(\left(M_n-M_{\infty}\right)^2\right)=0$ (quadratic convergence).
- (iii) $M_n=\mathbb{E}\left(M_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{F}_n\right)$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (this last property is referred to as the martingale $M$ being "closed at infinity").

**Optional stopping theorem, version 3.** Let $\left(M_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ be a martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ such that there exists $c>0$ with $\left|M_{n+1}(\omega)-M_n(\omega)\right| \leq c$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (this assumption ensures that the martingale does not make jumps of uncontrolled size: the simple symmetric random walk $S_n$ satisfies in particular this assumption). Let also $a, b>0$ and
$$
T=\inf \left\{n \in \mathbb{N}: M_n \leq-a \text { or } M_n \geq b\right\}.
$$
Observe that $T$ is a stopping time with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ and that $-a-c \leq M_{T \wedge n}(\omega) \leq b+c$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular,
$$
\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}\left(M_{T \wedge n}^2\right)<+\infty,
$$
so the stopped process $\left(M_{T \wedge n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ satisfies the assumptions of the first version of the martingale convergence theorem. By the conclusion of this theorem, the stopped martingale $\left(M_{T \wedge n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right)$ is closed, i.e. it admits a limit $\color{blue}{M_{T \wedge \infty}=M_T}$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(M_T\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(M_{T \wedge \infty}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(M_{T \wedge 0}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(M_0\right).
$$

Comment: I don't think the author is claiming that $T < \infty$ a.s.  It looks like they are just defining $M_T := M_{T \wedge \infty}$.

Comment: @user6247850 you meant $M_T$ is defined as the limit of $(M_{T \wedge n})_n$ and not as $M_T (\omega) = M_{T (\omega} (\omega)$?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, they are probably just defining $M_T = M_\infty$ on the event $\{T = \infty\}$.

Comment: That's an odd exposition of the OST for sure

Comment: @user6247850 $M_\infty$ might not exist in the extended real numbers, and fail to be measurable

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't paying attention to the conditions on $M$.  Then yeah, I think they are defining $M_T = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{T \wedge n}$, which is equal to $M_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$ on the event $\{T < \infty\}$.